# Azure DevOps Powershell get work item related to build pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, workitem, azure-devops-pipelines

I have a build pipeline with a trigger on new branch creation. The trigger works fine with me creating a new branch and linking a workitem task to the new branch.

I have tried to run the query through the API to retrieve the workitem associated to the build but it always comes back blank. I can retrieve the list of workitems in the project no problem.

The URI I am using is:

[https://dev.azure.com/{instance}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{build](https://dev.azure.com/%7Binstance%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/build/builds/%7Bbuild) id}/workitems?api-version=6.0

This returns a blank value. If I remove the "workitems" then I get a list of all the builds with one of the entries matching the build id. The PAT I am using has full access to the project (currently testing so have not been specific for the access).

This is the last step for me to complete and I can piece the whole puzzle.

UPDATE1: I have now noticed that in the pipeline log there is no related work item even though I create the branch from within the work item.

[image: Screenshot of build log]

UPDATE2: I notice if I do a commit and associated the work item then the build lists the related work item. Does not appear to work when creating a new branch, only comitting to that new branch

Comment: Erm... Do your builds have workitems associated? :)

Comment: @Grzegorz, that would defeat the object if I wasn't associating but at the same time I do mention "The trigger works fine with me creating a new branch and linking a workitem task to the new branch."

Answer (score 1):

Build pipeline adds related work items by reading the work items associated with the checkout commit.

> I have now noticed that in the pipeline log there is no related work item even though I create the branch from within the work item.

When you create the new branch in work item, you need to change the build branch in Build Pipeline.

[image]

Then the build will use the newly created branch to build pipeline, the work items will relate to the Build.

When you run the Rest API: [Builds - Get Build Work Items Refs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20work%20items%20refs?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), it will show the related work item.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/workitems?api-version=6.0
```

[image]